# What is the peak of the short circuit current

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, short-circuit

I have this problem:

> Consider the circuit below:
>
> [image]
>
> \$V_{in}\$ has an amplitude of 17V and a frequency of 125 kHz.
>
> What is the peak of the short circuit current between the terminals \$a\$ and \$b\$?

Okay so this is how I thought about solving the problem. First finding all the impedances with the formulas:

\$X_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}\$

\$X_L = j\omega L\$

Now creating mesh current equations, all currents going clockwise:

\$-V_{in}+X_{C1} \cdot i_1+X_L(i_1-i_2) = 0\$

\$ X_L(i_2-i1)+i_2\cdot R+X_{C2}(i_2-i_3)=0\$

\$X_{C2}(i_3-i_2)=0\$

Inserting all the values, setting \$V_{in}=17 \mbox{V}\$ to get the **peak value** and solving the equations with Maple we find that:

\$i_3=-0.029289+0.263783\cdot j\$

Taking the absolute vales we get: \$i_3=265.4042 \mbox{mA}\$, which I assumed was the correct answer. However, double checking with Lt-spice I get a different result for the peak value.

[image]

Who should I trust? My calculations or the simulation tool?

I hope someone can help me out.

**EDIT**

Another problem I have with the simulation tool, is that doesn't give me a consistent result of the peak value, as seen below.

[image]

Comment: Just throwing an idea: if you reduce the time step in the simulation, you’ll get a result that’s closer to ideal.

Comment: Assuming your model was correct, you should trust the tool.  For a simple ideal L-C circuit Its far less likely that the software made a mistake compared to hand solved equations.

Comment: @user4574 I made an edit to the post. Maybe you can help me out?

Comment: So far as i can see, your results match with a micro-ampere accuracy. I couldn’t see a problem in this. I don’t think high accuracy is important in this circuit.

Comment: @BenFM Although it's good accuracy, I need to give an answer in mA with 2 decimals precision. So I'm in a little bit of trouble here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want precise measurements you should not rely on the cursors: they are handy, but only for quick references, as you can see in the time values of the two readings. Instead, use `.meas` for an optional interval:

```
.meas Imax max I(V2) from 0 to 100n
```

Here I chose `100n` as the final time because I only wanted to measure the initial peak current.

You should also know your tool before you use it: inductors have a default series resistance of 1mΩ, which can be seen when right-clicking on the inductor (message at the bottom of the settings window). Also, there is a default `Rpar`, to allow damping, setting which can be altered in `Tools > Control Panel > Hacks! > Supply a min inductor damping...`. It seems to default to `gmin*L = 1e12*L`, so if your inductance is small enough, it may become influential enough. Directly setting `Rpar` to zero is much quicker and doesn't influence the rest of the schematic(s), since the Control Panel setting is remembered.

The capacitors also have the hidden `Rpar`, which seems to default to `gmin`, which isn't that much problematic. Still, since your example relies on ideal elements, you should probably take time to set to zero the builtin parasitic elements for both L and C. It's enough to do it once, for one, and then simply copy-paste for the rest.

Finally, you may want to impose a tighter timestep, for better resolution, and also disable waveform compression with `.opt plotwinsize=0`, since the default 300 points is not that much precise.

Considering your other question, it seems you need to rely on some simulator or another for your learning, so it would do you good to deal with the friendly, but rather spartan manual when things seem to not work properly. The [undocumented LTspice](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice) can provide additional help.

Comment: Thanks again for your very professional and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's solve this mathematically. We have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz95am.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input voltage is given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{in}\left(t\right)=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\cos\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)\tag1$$

In the complex form this input voltage can be written as:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}=\hat{\text{u}}_\text{in}\exp\left(\varphi\text{j}\right)\tag2$$

Where \$\text{j}^2=-1\$.

Now, the input impedance is given by:

$$\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{L}\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\text{||}\text{R}_2\right)}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}\text{||}\text{R}_2}=\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_1}+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{L}\left(\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2}{1+\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}}\right)}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2}{1+\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}}}\tag3$$

Now, the input current is given by:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{in}}}{\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{in}}}\tag4$$

And the current trough \$\text{R}_2\$ can be found using the current divider formula:

$$\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}=\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}_2}+\text{R}_2}\cdot\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{R}_1+\frac{\text{R}_2}{1+\omega\text{C}_2\text{R}_2\text{j}}}\tag5$$

Now, we can find \$\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\right|\$ when \$\text{R}_2\to0\$. Because you've already found an answer I used Mathematica to find it:

```
In[1]:=R1 = 3/10;
C1 = 20*10^(-9);
C2 = 330*10^(-9);
L = (33/10)*10^(-6);
w = 2*Pi*125*1000;
uin = 17;
\[Phi] = 0; FullSimplify[
 Limit[Abs[(((I*w*
         L))/(((I*w*
           L)) + (R1 + (((R2)*((1/(I*w*C2))))/(((1/(I*w*
                   C2))) + (R2))))))*((1/(I*w*C2))/((1/(I*w*C2)) + 
        R2))*((uin*
        Exp[\[Phi]*
          I])/((1/(I*w*
            C1)) + (((I*w*
              L)*((R1 + ((((1/(I*w*C2)))*(R2))/(((1/(I*w*
                    C2))) + (R2))))))/((I*w*
              L) + ((R1 + ((((1/(I*w*C2)))*(R2))/(((1/(I*w*
                    C2))) + (R2)))))))))], R2 -> 0]]

Out[1]=(1870 \[Pi]^2)/Sqrt[64000000 + 483472000 \[Pi]^2 + 1089 \[Pi]^4]

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]=0.265404
```

So, the exact expression is:

$$\lim_{\text{R}_2\to0}\left|\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{R}_2}\right|=\frac{1870\pi^2}{\sqrt{64000000+483472000\pi^2+1089\pi^4}}\approx0.265404\space\text{A}\tag6$$

Comment: Great, so you also get an answer of 265.40mA, that's good to see. This is also a really clear and well-written answer. I really appreciate the effort!

Comment: @Carl You're welcome, I happy that I could be of any help.